# What is the reason for having unreserved identifiers as built-in macros in gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, macros, history

Today I stumbled upon a rather interesting compiler error:

```
int main() {
  int const unix = 0; // error-line
  return unix;
}
```

Gives the following message with gcc 4.3.2 (yes, ancient...):

```
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

which is definitely quite confusing.

Fortunately, clang (3.0) is a little more helpful (as usual):

```
error: expected unqualified-id
  int const unix = 0
            ^
<built-in>:127:14: note: expanded from:
#define unix 1
             ^
```

I certainly did not expect `unix`, which is neither written in upper-case nor begin with underscore to be a macro, especially a built-in one.

I checked the predefined macros in gcc and there are 2 (on my platform) that use "unreserved" symbols:

```
$ g++ -E -dM - < /dev/null | grep -v _
#define unix 1
#define linux 1
```

All the others are "well-behaved" macros with leading underscores, using the traditional reserved identifiers, sample:

```
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1

#define __unix__ 1
#define __unix 1

#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __x86_64 1
#define __amd64 1
#define _LP64 1
```

(it's a mess and there does not seem to be any particular order...)

Furthermore, there are lots of "similar" symbols, so I guess there is an issue of backward compatibility...

So, where do the `unix` and `linux` macros come from ?

Comment: Works fine in gcc 4.7,seems like some bug :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Ah nice, I am using gcc 4.3.2 (at work).

Comment: I added the historical tag, I believe it to be historical at least.

Comment: Nice to know. Normally I see the opposite, like programmers that for no reason (except may be the childish passion for the forbidden) use names like `__MY_INCLUDE_FILE__` instead of legal ones for include guards.

Comment: @6502: I don't think it's a passion for the forbidden, I think it's cargo cult programming.  People saw identifiers like that used for include guards in the headers provided with the compiler (or with an SDK), and started to do likewise.  I think that the early Windows SDK was a big contributor to this; MS has been cleaning up that kind of thing in the Windows SDK, but the early damage was around for a while (and I'd guess a lot of it pre-dated the C standard).

Comment: @Xeo: thanks, I didn't even know such a tag existed :)

Comment: @6502 how is `__MY_INCLUDE_FILE__` illegal at all? And how do _you_ do include guards, then? I don't see anything "childish" in that at all...

Comment: @fge: double underscores in any part of an identifier are reserved for the compiler implementer. Also are reserved single underscores at the beginning when followed by an uppercase letter (any use) or single underscore at the beginning followed by a lowercase letter (for global identifiers). By using forbidden names you can get into very hard to debug problems (e.g. your program crashing before main even starts simply because you decided to name a global variable `_init`). Just avoid underscores at beginning (they're also ugly) and use for example `MYFILE_H_INCLUDED` instead.

Comment: @Xeo: much better to use the [history] tag for this. [historical] is a bit 'polluted' with questions about SQL

Answer (score 19, accepted):

gcc does not fully conform to any C standard by default.

Invoke it with `-ansi`, `-std=c99`, or `-std=c1x` and `unix` won't be predefined.  (`-std=c1x` <strike>will probably become</strike> became `-std=c11` in a <strike>future</strike> more recent gcc release.)

It's a bit confusing that this is documented in the separate manual for the GNU preprocessor, not in the gcc manual.

Quoting the GNU preprocessor documentation (`info cpp`, version 4.5):

> The C standard requires that all system-specific macros be part of 
>   the "reserved namespace".  All names which begin with two underscores,
>   or an underscore and a capital letter, are reserved for the compiler
>   and library to use as they wish.  However, historically
>   system-specific macros have had names with no special prefix; for
>   instance, it is common to find `unix' defined on Unix systems.  For
>   all such macros, GCC provides a parallel macro with two underscores
>   added at the beginning and the end.  If `unix' is defined,
>   `__unix__' will be defined too. There will never be more than two
>   underscores; the parallel of `_mips' is `__mips__'.
>
> When the `-ansi' option, or any `-std' option that requests strict
>   conformance, is given to the compiler, all the system-specific
>   predefined macros outside the reserved namespace are suppressed.  The
>   parallel macros, inside the reserved namespace, remain defined.
>
> We are slowly phasing out all predefined macros which are outside the
>   reserved namespace.  You should never use them in new programs, and we
>   encourage you to correct older code to use the parallel macros
>   whenever you find it.  We don't recommend you use the system-specific
>   macros that are in the reserved namespace, either.  It is better in
>   the long run to check specifically for features you need, using a tool
>   such as `autoconf'.

The current version of the manual is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros).

Comment: Cool, so it was indeed historical! I have precognitive powers! :) +1

Comment: @Xeo: Precognition after the fact?  Now that's a superpower I'd like to have!

Comment: Why? I added the tag long ago to the question. :P

Comment: @KeithThompson: many thanks. Now I not only know that they are working on removing them, but I also know how to kick them out should I need it. Do you also happen to know why they were introduced in the first place ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I believe that the `unix` macro in particular was introduced long before ANSI standardized the language and established which identifiers are reserved to the implementation.  Pre-ANSI C commonly required a "creepy maze of #ifdefs" because of things like this.  The "Best One Liner" winner of the 1987 [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org/) took advantage of it: `main() { printf(&unix["\021%six\012\0"],(unix)["have"]+"fun"-0x60);}`

Comment: Some extra info: The macro linux is listed as an obsolete operating system identifying macro on the list of pre-defined compiler macros at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Operating_Systems#Linux