# i386 macro predefined in make or gcc?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I've been attempting to make a folder for each architecture my code can support.  In this folder are platform specific files to include.  I include them as follows:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define ASSTR(x) STR(x)

#include ASSTR(ARCHITECTURE/sizes.h)
```

My compilation line in make looks like this:

```
gcc -o $@ -c $< -DARCHITECTURE=i386
```

Which works, until I define ARCHITECTURE to be i386.  When this happens, it looks for 1/sizes.h, so I assume it's already defined somewhere.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677390/what-is-the-reason-for-having-unreserved-identifiers-as-built-in-macros-in-gcc/8677556#8677556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the C preprocessor (`cpp`), which is called by `gcc`, defines `i386` (for i386 systems). You can find out what it defines like so:

```
touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h; rm foo.h
```

This method is described by the `cpp` man page, under `-d`, with the character `M` (so, `-dM`):

> Instead of the normal output, generate a list of **#define** directives for all the macros defined during the execution of the preprocessor, including predefined macros. This gives you a way of finding out what is predefined in your version of the preprocessor. Assuming you have no file foo.h, the command
>
> ```
>     touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h
> ```
>
> will show all the predefined macros.

Comment: Makes sense.  I still want to use a separate directory for each architecture, so I probably wont use `#ifdef i386`.

Comment: @roadkillguy: Perhaps to aid in future portability (and to get around the problem), you could use something like `linux-i386` or `solaris-i386` or whatever platform you're using.

Comment: It doesn't define `i386` if you invoke it in standard-conforming mode (such as `-ansi` or `-std=c99`).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677390/what-is-the-reason-for-having-unreserved-identifiers-as-built-in-macros-in-gcc/8677556#8677556

Comment: @DanFego that's what I've done.  Is x86 a valid alias for i386?  Technically I'm messing around with grub and kernel development, so it's neither linux nor solaris XD.